# Windows 7 Symlink to network drive root

Tags: symbolic-link, smb, mklink

My Ubuntu server provides storage to my Windows 7 workstation through the use of SMB and network drives. One symlink currently links from a network drive to my iTunes library folder. Within that folder there is a TV Shows folder that I'd like to link to another network drive that has been given the letter I:/. I tried using mklink but I continue to get an error

```
The file or directory is not a reparse point.
```

Can I even link to drive roots? My command was the form

```
mklink /d "C:/iTunes Media/TV Shows" I:/
```

Comment: It is certainly possible to do...

Comment: What command or syntax am I missing?

Comment: have you tried just going to that directory, and then doing: `mklink /d I:/`

Comment: Just did, but mklink requires both link and target designators... I used . for link and it said I couldn't create the folder that already exists

Comment: Sounds like something else is going on then. Sorry.

Comment: Yep you're right... I think it's because I'm creating a symbolic link inside a folder that was created as a symbolic link. I created a link from the Desktop and I:/ worked fine.